# Quickly Solving a High-Order Root System of Equations of Arbitrary Form

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I have the following system of equations that involve some rather complicated exponents:

$$
\left\{\frac{\mathit{a} \sigma ^{41/34}}{\mathit{m}^{8/119} \mathcal{M}^{28/17}}=1,\frac{\mathit{b}\mathit{q}\mathit{m}^{2/3} \mathcal{M}^3}{\sqrt{\sigma }}=1,\frac{\mathit{f} \mathit{c} \mathit{m}^{436/357}}{\sigma ^{48/17} \mathcal{M}^{38/51}}=1\right\}
$$

I'd like Mathematica to find the positive, real solutions to this equation for $\mathcal{M}$, $\sigma$, and $q$, ($a$, $b$, $c$, $m$, and $f$ remain undefined) and `Solve` is able to do this, but it literally takes ~30 minutes to solve the expression:

```
FullSimplify[Abs[Cases[({sigma, M, q} /. 
  Solve[expression, {sigma, M, q}]), _?(FreeQ[N[#, 16], Complex] && 
    FreeQ[N[#, 16], Positive] &)][[1]]], 
      Assumptions -> Join[assume, # > 0 & /@ coeffs]]
```

I noticed if I make one simple change to the expression, multiplying the RHS by the denominators, i.e.

$$
\left\{\mathit{a} \sigma ^{41/34}=\mathit{m}^{8/119} \mathcal{M}^{28/17},\mathit{b}\mathit{q}\mathit{m}^{2/3} \mathcal{M}^3 = \sqrt{\sigma },\mathit{f} \mathit{c} \mathit{m}^{436/357} = \sigma ^{48/17} \mathcal{M}^{38/51}\right\}
$$

...then the expression solves in about 30 seconds. Unfortunately, it is the first form that is spat out by my previous lines of code, and that form is not the same for each evaluation.

I'm wondering why the first solve is so much more expensive than the second, and if there are strategies I can use when simplifying expressions to guarantee that `Solve` won't choke on them.

Comment: For starters, when you divide you need to check for all possible zeroes ...

Comment: see if `Denominator[ ]` helps you out ...

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I didn't have `assume` definition up in the question, but all quantities are real and greater than zero.

Comment: I routinely do `exprs=Apply[Subtract,eqns,{1}]; neweqns=Thread[Numerator[Together[exprs]]==0];`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That works great! I guess the main overhead here is the "checking for zeroes" part.

Comment: (1) The denominators add a considerable overhead. Each gives rise to a new variable, call it `denRecip`, and a new (nonlinear) equation of the form `denRecip*den==1`. That can get into complexity pretty easily.

Comment: (2) For systems of this particular sort, you might want to preprocess using `PowerExpand[Log[lhs]]==0`, then substitute new variables for the logs of the variables of interest and solve the (now linear) system for those. This assumes a power-expanded variation of the original equations is okay. For typical ranges of interest with systems of this type, it often is.